Do we have general polynomial equation $f(x,y) = 0$ of degree $d$ which has cusp singular point at origin?

Do we have general polynomial equation $f(x,y) = 0$ of degree $d$ which has cusp singular point at origin?

I want to explicitly compute something in singularity theory for the cusp $X = Z(f) \subset \mathbb{C}^{2}$, but I don't have any idea to see how such polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree $d$ should be in general.

How about $y^2=x^4$?
